Early 90s Movie about a dark haired and bespectacled guy
I saw this movie probable early 1990s.  
It featured a dark haired and bespectacled guy, who was quite low-key or even lonely.  Somehow, he got or was given this gadget that is somewhat similar to what the Tamagochi toy was.  
It could communicate to him, copy sounds, etc.  One scene was that he was watching a concert of an orchestra (he wore a tuxedo), and he had that gadget with him.  It suddenly imitated the orchestra, and it became louder and he could not control it. 
He wrestled with the gadget but to no avail, he had to leave the show in embarrassment.  It came to a point that he could no longer control it.

Do you remember language / country of this movie? Any particular detail about the actors? was it live action / animation? color / B&W?

Reminds me of "Electric Dreams".

I think you're talking about "Electric Dreams", 1984.  Check out this video at 30:00.
Miles has dark hair, wears glasses and is socially awkward.  He purchases a computer to help keep him organized, but the machine becomes sentient.  Miles' love interest is his next-door neighbour, Madeline, who plays cello in the orchestra.  She invites Miles to a performance.  During the performance, the computer listens through Miles' pager, and plays synthesized music along with the melody.  Miles tries to turn off the pager, but the computer reconnects.  The computer's music becomes louder and more sophisticated as Miles tries to stop it, and the other patrons get angrier at the interruption. Finally Miles runs to the washroom and flushes the pager. 

We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.
